# Why it can't come out the next parse? About Scrapy crawl

Tags: python, scrapy

The problem is, the code can't go to the next page and parse_item

Here's my code:

```
    allowed_domains = ['http://192.168.99.100/']
start_urls = ['http://192.168.99.100:32768/properties/index_00000.html',]

# Rules for horizontal and vertical crawling
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[@itemprop="url"]')),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[contains(@class,"next")]'),
         callback='parse_item', follow=True),
```

Is there any issues with the code?
I copied this code from the book  ch03

Comment: try changing your allowed domains `allowed_domains = ['192.168.99.100']`

Answer (score -1):

It's strange.
I just modify the url in the code of the book, I just get the wrong output.
I don't know why, but I will avoid direct use the ip as the url.

so the answer is, change the 192.168.99.100 in the code to web and before you should change the /etc/hosts and add '192.168.99.100 web' to the bottom.